# Insert data into multiple tables using one form

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data in 2 tables using one form.

This is my form

```
<form action="don.php" method="post">
<tr><td>
    <p>
        <label for="nume">Nume:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="nume" id="nume" autocomplete="off"></td>
    </p>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>
    <p>
        <label for="prenume">Prenume:</label></td>
       <td> <input type="text" name="prenume" id="prenume" autocomplete="off"></td>
    </p></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <p>
        <label for="grupa">Numar telefon:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="numar" id="numar" autocomplete="off"></td>
    </p></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <p>
        <label for="grupa">Suma:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="suma" id="suma" autocomplete="off"></td>
    </p></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <p>
        <label for="grupa">Data:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="data" id="data" autocomplete="off"></td>
    </p></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <p>
        <label for="grupa">IBAN:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="iban" id="iban" autocomplete="off"></td>
    </p></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Donează" onclick="alert('Operatiune finalizata cu succes. Va multumim!')"></td>
</form>
```

And this is my PHP code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if(!$con)
    {
        die("Nu se poate face conexiunea la baza de date" . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("laborator",$con);
    $sql="INSERT INTO donator (nume, prenume, numar_telefon) VALUES ('$_POST[nume]','$_POST[prenume]','$_POST[numar]')";
    $sql="INSERT INTO donatie (suma, data_donatie, IBAN) VALUES ('$_POST[suma]','$_POST[data]','$_POST[iban]')";
    mysql_query($sql,$con);
    mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

When I press the submit button it shows me the alert that my dates were inserted, but only the second `INSERT` works. Table `donator` is empty.
What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: mysqli's multi query works well http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: you're also open to some massive SQL injection

Comment: **Important:** Validate your input: http://www.dreamhost.com/blog/2013/05/22/php-security-user-validation-and-sanitization-for-the-beginner

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You must call `mysql_query()` for every query.

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO donator ...";
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO donatie ...";
mysql_query($sql1, $con);
mysql_query($sql2, $con);
```

---

**Important**

`mysql_query()` is deprecated! Please use `mysqli_query()` http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php

You can also use `mysqli_multi_query()` http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.multi-query.php

```
$query = "INSERT INTO donator ...; INSERT INTO donatie ...;";
mysqli_multi_query($link, $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You run your queries with the same variable `$sql`. You should call them differentely like that and call them after.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO donator (nume, prenume, numar_telefon) VALUES ('mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[nume])','mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[prenume])','mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[numar])')";
$sql2="INSERT INTO donatie (suma, data_donatie, IBAN) VALUES ('mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[suma])','mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[data])','mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[iban])')";
```

Otherwise, you must change your post values by protecting them. [Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Then, you have to switch to new mysql syntax for PHP, like mysqli or PDO. THe mysql syntax you are using is deprecated.

Comment: I already tried to call them differently. And it doesn't work neither with sql . =...

Comment: Because you have to call them with different queries

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your $sql variable. Save them as separate variables, or run the first query before declaring the second one.

That said, you should REALLY consider both switching two either PDO or mysqli for your queries rather than the mysql extension and also looking into prepared statements and properly sanitizing strings, because you're very vulnerable to sql injections.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this It will work perfectly.

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['server']="localhost";
$GLOBALS['username']="root";
$GLOBALS['password']="*****";
$GLOBALS['database']="performance";

$GLOBALS['conn']= mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//echo "Connected successfully";    

$GLOBALS['db'] = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);

$sql="INSERT INTO animals (id,name) VALUES('2211','vidya');";
$sql .="INSERT INTO birds (id,fame) VALUES('2211','viddi');";
//mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
//mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
if (mysqli_multi_query($GLOBALS['db'], $sql)) {
    echo "New records created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be nice if you could also explain as to why your suggestion should work and where  the OP might've made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This is a example of one form data insert for a multiple tables.

Here html form has one submit button. "ok" name is the submit button name.

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cultureframework");
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySql:".mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ok']))
{
    $ip=$_POST['ip'];
    $date=$_POST['date'];
    $gender=$_POST['gender'];
    $age=$_POST['age'];
    $tenure=$_POST['tenure'];
    //-------------------------------------
    $caring_past_1=$_POST['caring_past_1'];
    $caring_present_1=$_POST['caring_present_1'];
    $caring_future_1=$_POST['caring_future_1'];
    $caring_past_2=$_POST['caring_past_2'];
    $caring_present_2=$_POST['caring_present_2'];
    $caring_future_2=$_POST['caring_future_2'];

    //-------------------------------------

        $insert="INSERT INTO `generalinfo`(`ip`,`datez`,`gender`,`age`,`tenure`) VALUES('$ip','$date','$gender','$age','$tenure')";
        $query=mysqli_query($con,$insert);

        $ins="INSERT INTO `caring`(`caring_past_1`,`caring_present_1`,`caring_future_1`,`caring_past_2`,
        `caring_present_2`,`caring_future_2`) VALUES('$caring_past_1','$caring_present_1','$caring_future_1','$caring_past_2','$caring_present_2','$caring_future_2')";
        $quy=mysqli_query($con,$ins);   
}

?>
```