# How to insert data into two different tables using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data into two different tables using PHP and MySQL but the data is only inserted into the second table only. Can someone please explain to me why and help me fix the problem. So I read this [StackOverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466422/insert-data-into-multiple-tables-using-one-form) but am not sure if this is Object Oriented style PHP because I had no luck making it work for me.

```
<?php
//outputing php errors in development
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//adding database config
include_once 'config.php';


//processing post data
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{
// variables for input data

            $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
            $company_address = $_POST['company_address'];
            $name_of_vessel = $_POST['name_of_vessel'];
            $official_vessel_number = $_POST['official_vessel_number'];
            $port_of_registry = $_POST['port_of_registry'];
            $gross_tonnage = $_POST['gross_tonnage'];
            $imo_number = $_POST['imo_number'];
            $call_sign = $_POST['call_sign'];
            $permit_number = $_POST['permit_number'];
            $date_of_issue_op = $_POST['date_of_issue_op'];
            $date_of_expiry_op =$_POST ['date_of_expiry_op'];
            $date_of_expiry_sp = $_POST['date_of_expiry_sp'];
            $date_of_issue_sp =$_POST ['date_of_issue_sp'];

// SQL query for inserting data into the database



      $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO `customers` (`company_name`,`company_address`,`name_of_vessel`,`official_vessel_number`, `port_of_registry`, `gross_tonnage`, `imo_number`, `call_sign`, `permit_number`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

      $stmt->bind_param('sssssssss',$company_name, $company_address, $name_of_vessel, $official_vessel_number, $port_of_registry, $gross_tonnage, $imo_number, $call_sign, $permit_number);

$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO `permits` (`date_of_issue_op`, `date_of_expiry_op`, `date_of_expiry_sp`, `date_of_issue_sp`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

      $stmt->bind_param('ssss',$date_of_issue_op , $date_of_expiry_op, $date_of_expiry_sp, $date_of_issue_sp );
      if($stmt->execute()){
            echo "<span style='background-color:green; padding:6px; color:white; font-size:16px;'>Permit created successfully </span>";
      }else{
            echo "<p align=center>Error inserting data.</p>";
            echo mysqli_error($link);
      }

}else{
       echo "<p align=center>Empty form submitted</p>";
}


?>
```

Comment: It looks to me like you're only performing `$stmt->execute()` after the second statement. You would probably need to execute it twice, once for each insert.

Comment: use 2 different variables : $stmt1 for the first and $stmt2 for the seconde one OR execute $stmt then prepare the second query, in your actual code, after preparing the first statment you just overwrite it with the second one

Comment: So please how do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mabrouki Fakhri suggested, for example:

```
// sql query for inserting data into database



$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO `customers` (`company_name`,`company_address`,`name_of_vessel`,`official_vessel_number`, `port_of_registry`, `gross_tonnage`, `imo_number`, `call_sign`, `permit_number`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$stmt->bind_param('sssssssss',$company_name, $company_address, $name_of_vessel, $official_vessel_number, $port_of_registry, $gross_tonnage, $imo_number, $call_sign, $permit_number);

$stmt1 = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO `permits` (`date_of_issue_op`, `date_of_expiry_op`, `date_of_expiry_sp`, `date_of_issue_sp`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

$stmt1->bind_param('ssss',$date_of_issue_op , $date_of_expiry_op, $date_of_expiry_sp, $date_of_issue_sp );
  if($stmt->execute() && $stmt1->execute()){
        echo "<span style='background-color:green; padding:6px; color:white; font-size:16px;'>Permit created successfully </span>";
  }else{
        echo "<p align=center>Error inserting data.</p>";
        echo mysqli_error($link);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two times

```
$link->prepare
```

and the second overwrite the first

Comment: So please how do I fix this? how do I go about this

Answer (score 0):

You should have two different statements, (i.e. stmt1 , stmt2 ) and prepare, bind both of them. then execute both of them on two different statements also.